# How long should a respondent in an investigation have before they are investigated?

Tags: human-resources, bullying, complaint

How long, is too long, for a respondent to have, whilst responding to an accusation of workplace bullying?

For context:
The accused has my official complaint for 2+ months and has yet to be investigated (due to holidays, witness interviews etc).. is this normal? 10 weeks to come up with a response?

Comment: Hello LOLW, welcome to The Workplace. Your question in its current form is unclear. Please specify your location, and also add your goal.

Answer (score 2):

> How long, is too long, for a respondent to have, whilst responding to
>   an accusation of workplace bullying?

Given the few details you have written, there's no way for anyone to say X is too long, but Y isn't.

This depends on local laws, and the practices of the recipient of your accusations. In some locales, there is a specific period of time during which you must get some sort of response. In others, there is no such requirement. For some investigating groups, they act immediately. For others, they can take months or just bury your accusations forever.

Ask whoever you sent your accusation to how long you should expect to wait for a formal response.

Comment: The OP could also raise a grievance on the grounds that nothing has been done

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what would be too long. However, I would expect that the person in question would be told very early that they were accused of bullying, and whether that accusation is true or not, any future bullying would be a very, very bad idea for their career.

Comment: You are assuming that the allegation is in good faith not all are

Answer (score 0):

> is this normal? 10 weeks to come up with a response?

No, not if the company is taking the complaint seriously. Then they would deal with it in a very short time frame.

Comment: Actually no you do have to allow appropriate time otherwise the accused person my well run the defence I was railroaded and denied natural justice I would expect 3-4 weeks for the initial hearing.

Comment: What about 15 weeks before he responds ? Is that fair on the complaintant?